# Как вернуть первое и второе значение функции? const result1 и const result2 - должно быть неизменно. Нужно править саму function compose(...args)

Tags: javascript

```
   function compose(...args) {
    let items = args.reverse();
    let result = '';
    for (i in items) {
        result = items[i](result);
    };
    let result1 = function (param) {
        return param + result;
    };
    let result2 = function () {
        return param + result;
    }();
};
const result1 = compose(
    prevResult => prevResult + 'o',
    prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
    prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
    prevResult => prevResult + 'e',
)('h');
const result2 = compose(
    prevResult => prevResult + 'o',
    prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
    prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
    prevResult => prevResult + 'e',
    () => 'h',
);
console.log(result1); // 'hello'
console.log(result2); // 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае, без каких либо ограничений на передаваемые функции задачу решить невозможно, так как нельзя будет определить будут вызывать результат функции как функцию или как значение.

Однако, если ограничить условие так, что при передаче последним параметром функции без параметров - результат должен быть строкой, а в противном случае функцией, то в момент вызова функции compose можно узнать какой именно результат ожидается.

Определить количество формальных параметров функции можно с помощью свойства [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

В результате можно получить следующий код:

```js
function compose(...args) {
  var last = args.pop(); // берем последнюю функцию
  if (!last.length) { // если функция без параметров
    return args.reduceRight((param, func) => func(param), last()); // сразу возвращаем результат
  }
  // в противном случае возвращаем функцию, которая возвращает результат
  return function nested(arg = "") {
    return args.reduceRight((param, func) => func(param), last(arg));
  }
};
const result1 = compose(
  prevResult => prevResult + 'o',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'e',
)('h');
const result2 = compose(
  prevResult => prevResult + 'o',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'e',
  () => 'h',
);
console.log(result1); // 'hello'
console.log(result2); // 'hello'
```

---

Если не делать таких ограничений, можно всегда возвращать функцию, переопределив у котором метод `.toString()` для получения результата, но в этом случае результат не будет совпадать в вызове `console.log`, если эта функция не переопределена так, что вызывает просто `toString` у получаемого объекта.

```js
function compose(...args) {
  function nested(arg = "") {
    return args.reduceRight((param, func) => func(param), arg);
  }
  nested.toString = function() {
    return args.reduceRight((param, func) => func(param), '');
  }

  return nested;
};
const result1 = compose(
  prevResult => prevResult + 'o',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'e',
)('h');
const result2 = compose(
  prevResult => prevResult + 'o',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'l',
  prevResult => prevResult + 'e',
  () => 'h',
);
console.log(result1); // 'hello'
console.log(result2 + ''); // 'hello'
```

Comment: Вот с ограничениями вполне подходит. Только Вы пропустили function в строчке ```return nested(arg = "")```. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @ТарасПоцыкайло, поправил

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы этого хотите добится?

```
function compose(...args) {
  let items = args.reverse();
  let result = "";
  for (i in items) {
    result = items[i](result);
  }

  return function(param) {
    return param + result;
  };
}
const result1 = compose(
  prevResult => prevResult + "o",
  prevResult => prevResult + "l",
  prevResult => prevResult + "l",
  prevResult => prevResult + "e"
)("h");

const result2 = compose(
  prevResult => prevResult + "o",
  prevResult => prevResult + "l",
  prevResult => prevResult + "l",
  prevResult => prevResult + "e",
  () => "h"
)("");

console.log(result1); // 'hello'
console.log(result2); // 'hello'
```

Comment: Извините, не правильно задал вопрос (поправил условие)